# SQL Server- PIVOT table. transform row into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to convert rows into columns. here is my query

```
SELECT M.urn,
       M.eventdate,
       M.eventlocation,
       M.eventroom,
       M.eventbed,
       N.time
FROM   admpatevents M
       INNER JOIN admpattransferindex N
               ON M.urn = N.urn
                  AND M.eventseqno = N.eventseqno
                  AND M.eventdate = N.eventdate
WHERE  M.urn = 'F1002754364'
       AND M.eventcode = 'TFRADMIN'
```

Current result

```
URN           Date      Location    Room    Bed  Time
F1002754364 20121101    EDEXPRESS   4-152   02      0724
F1002754364 20121101    CARDSURG    3-110   02      1455
F1002754364 20121102    CHEST UNIT  6-129-GL04      1757
```

required result

```
F1002754364    20121101    EDEXPRESS   4-152   02  0724 20121101   CARDSURG    3-110   02  1455 20121102   CHEST UNIT  6-129-GL    04  1757
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server you can use both the `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` functions to transform this data.  If you know how many values to you will have then you can hard-code the values similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
    select urn,
        value,
        col +'_'+ CAST(rn as varchar(10)) as col
    from 
    (
        SELECT M.urn,
            cast(M.eventdate as varchar(50)) eventdate,
            M.eventlocation,
            M.eventroom,
            M.eventbed,
            cast(N.time as varchar(50)) time,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by m.urn order by m.eventdate) rn
        FROM   admpatevents M
        INNER JOIN admpattransferindex N
            ON M.urn = N.urn
            AND M.eventseqno = N.eventseqno
            AND M.eventdate = N.eventdate
        WHERE  M.urn = 'F1002754364'
            AND M.eventcode = 'TFRADMIN'
    ) src1
    unpivot
    (
        value 
        for col in (eventdate, eventlocation, eventroom, eventbed, time)
    ) unpiv
) src2
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in ([eventdate_1], [eventlocation_1], [eventroom_1], [eventbed_1], [time_1],
                [eventdate_2], [eventlocation_2], [eventroom_2], [eventbed_2], [time_2],
                [eventdate_3], [eventlocation_3], [eventroom_3], [eventbed_3], [time_3])
) piv
```

*Note- not tested*

If you have an unknown number of columns, then you can use dynamic sql similar to this:

```
DECLARE  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name +'_'+ cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                        select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by m.urn order by m.eventdate) rn
                        FROM   admpatevents M
                        INNER JOIN admpattransferindex N
                            ON M.urn = N.urn
                            AND M.eventseqno = N.eventseqno
                            AND M.eventdate = N.eventdate
                        WHERE  M.urn = 'F1002754364'

                    ) t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id IN (object_id('admpatevents'), object_id('admpattransferindex')) and
                         C.name not in ('urn') -- add any other columns your want to exclude
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
     from
     (
       select urn, value, col +''_''+ CAST(rn as varchar(10)) as col
       from
       (
            SELECT M.urn,
                cast(M.eventdate as varchar(20)) eventdate,
                M.eventlocation,
                M.eventroom,
                M.eventbed,
                cast(N.time as varchar(20)) time,
                ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by m.urn order by m.eventdate) rn
            FROM   admpatevents M
            INNER JOIN admpattransferindex N
                ON M.urn = N.urn
                AND M.eventseqno = N.EVENTseqno
                AND M.eventdate = N.eventdate
            WHERE  M.urn = ''F1002754364''

       ) x
       unpivot
       (
         value
         for col in (eventdate, eventlocation, eventroom, eventbed, time)
       ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c1cd/16)

Comment: thanks for the help.I am getting error when I ran both statements.
First statement error:The type of column "eventlocation" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.
Second Statement error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Thanks again

Comment: @Matt The datatypes need to be the same on all columns being unpivoted. So you will have to perform the conversion similar to what I did for the eventdate.  If you want, please create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and some sample data so I can test. :)

Comment: First statement worked after changing the datatype as you mentioned.
second statement, has some minor issues like ')' . I tried to change ')' around but didn't work. let me create schema in SQL fiddle. I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: @Matt see my edit, it is working now on this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c1cd/16